# C++ checksum CRC32 validation

Tags: c++, 7zip, crc32

I am using 7zip CHA32 tool to  validate my checksum 32 algorithm. The algorithm gives the correct value if and only if the size of the data buffer is multiple of 4. If the size of the buffer is different, the algorithm gives the proper checksum if I pad an extra '00' byte into the buffer. Are any there any generic C++ algorithms that might work without the contrainsts of the data size ? thanks

Comment: Are there any issues with adding extra padding (usually a maximum of 3 bytes for a CRC32 algorithm).  Use the remainder operator to determine the quantity of padding bytes.

Comment: I have a modulus of 3 extra bytes (size is constant) and I pad one extra byte. Problem occurs when I try to validate the calculated checksum with 7Zip CHA 32, I get different values with and without padded byte.

Comment: To align with my validation procedure, i am trying to adapt my algorithm with 7zip CHA 32 algorithm !

Comment: You may want to use a different tool to validate your CRC32 implementation.  Check out the NIST site, See [NIST CRC32](https://math.nist.gov/oommf/doc/userguide12b1/userguide/Cyclic_Redundancy_Check_crc.html) or http://www.nist.gov

Comment: What is 7zip cha32? Google doesn't provide any relevant results. What is its relation to CRC32? The CRC algorithm itself does not require padding.

Comment: it is an extension that comes along with 7zip.I have been using that to validate the checksum that i calculate with my algorithm. My question is "if 7zip CHA 32 can calculate the checksum of anysize, why not my algorithm?" i am looking for a generic algorithm which can work with any data size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRC-32 doesn't require you to pad your input. For example `crc32("abc")` and `crc32("abc\0")` will have different outputs.

There should be a second function or a parameter that defaults to 0 for the initial value of the hash. This is used for extending the hash. `crc32("cd", crc32("ab")) == crc32("abcd")`. So just add the last few bytes.

You will end up with something like this:

```
std::uint32_t padded_crc32(const char* data, std::size_t size, std::uint32_t initial_value = 0) {
    const char padding[3] = {0, 0, 0};
    std::uint32_t unpadded_crc32 = crc32(data, size, initial_value);  // Or however you call it
    int padding_size = (4 - (size % 4)) % 4;
    return crc32(padding, padding_size, unpadded_crc32);
}
```

Comment: Finally, i implemented the CRC32 algortim based on these functions and they work as expected  "http://home.thep.lu.se/~bjorn/crc/"